# Parenthesis are appearing strangely in some software eg chrome's element inspector and VS Code

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, text-formatting

Whenever I type parenthesis in some software, such as VS code and Chrome Inspector, I get this long Vertical Line .

I do not get this problem in notepad or word.

[image]

[image]

Comment: More information about your environment and operating system is required. If this is in Windows, does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: Oh no you can't ask a question like this without even stating in subject or body what software it is .   Even if we can see. That's really no good at all. People need to look things up via text search

Comment: Do you have something like Word installed? If so, does it happen if you type a ) there? And what happens if you change the font? It almost looks like a corrupt font.

Comment: @barlop , this is happening everywhere , not related with any software . Even when I inspect Element in Chrome it shows Vertical lines where there is a parenthesis . If I could find this using Google Search , I would not be wasting my time asking such questions here . You don't know what the problems is or don't want to help , that's fine . No need to put such comments like "You can't  ask questions..... "

Comment: @Kruz You haven't understood my comment. I am not saying you haven't searched. This website is a database of questions and answers. Your question is meant to help people not just you. So keywords within your question title help. Also in your body too, and for other reasons.

Comment: @LPChip, I just checked , It's not happening in World or Notepad .

Comment: @Kruz so " this is happening everywhere , not related with any software "  <-- is not correct. And all the more reason why as I said you should  have a more descriptive title, you need to learn that

Comment: @barlop , Okay . I could not think of a suitable title for this problem . That's why I kept it like this .

Comment: @harrymc , I am using W10 . I haven't checked it Safe Mode .

Comment: @Kruz what if you make the font courier new? what is the font?  what other editors is the issue happening in?

Comment: @barlop , See this image https://ibb.co/2SDZNmh    . Do you think this is a font related issue ?

Comment: Check Safe mode to know if this is caused by some installed product.

Comment: strange problem, i've added your image into your question..

Comment: it looks like only the closing parenthesis, is that right?!